# "illegal character" error when Watir execute_script

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webdriver, watir-webdriver

I am fetching JavaScript code through a textarea in the User Interface and then executing the code in my app like this:

User input:

```
text = 'I am fine!!! ';
return text.replace(/(.+)\s+$/g, '$1’);
```

However, in rails, escape character get added to the user input in the textarea:

```
"text = 'hello how are you? ';\\d\r\nreturn text.replace(/(.+)\\s+$/g, '$1’);"
```

So the execute_script statement gives an 'illegal character' error.

```
browser.execute_script("text = 'hello how are you? ';\\d\r\nreturn text.replace(/(.+)\\s+$/g, '$1’);")
```

How can I get rid of escape characters without using regex so that execute_script runs fine?

Comment: I do not understand what you are doing or why. Users typically don't input javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
browser.execute_script("text = 'hello how are you? '; return text.replace(/(.+)\\s+$/g, '$1');")
```

**BUT! Why on Earth do you need it?**

It is a very strange case and I am adding +1 to Dave's comment. It is not a typical user action to do some javascript magic. Try to think again about what are you doing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered trying [String#gsub!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-gsub!) for this?
Here is how I might have approached it:

```
test = "\\d\r\nreturn text.replace(/(.+)\\s+$/g, '$1’);"
=> "\\d\r\nreturn text.replace(/(.+)\\s+$/g, '$1’)"
test.gsub!(/[\d\n\r\\d]/, '')
=> "return text.replace(/(.+)s+$/"
```

If you don't want to overwrite it, you could also use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-gsub), to return a modified copy

```
test.gsub(/[\d\n\r\\d]/, '')
=> "return text.replace(/(.+)s+$/"
```

You can obviously customize the regex to customize your need. Also be careful with smart quotes like the closing quotation mark for $1 as `’` is not the same as `'`